# Is our Beta label being removed?

Tags: discussion

Quantum Computing and Matter Modeling just learned that their Beta labels are being removed. Is it happening here too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, we had only 950 questions from the 1,000 needed to move out of beta.

Comment: We'll be there by December 16th for sure!

Comment: We were well beyond 1000 questions when [the 58 other sites graduated out of Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-58-sites-that-just-left-beta). That post said "we allowed the communities to stay in Beta if they didn’t feel ready to leave that state yet". Does that mean that you (the diamond moderators of Cardano.SE) told SE that you didn't feel we were ready? That's totally okay if you did, but I'm just wondering if that happened, or if they just missed us because we weren't (yet) at 1000 questions at the time that they checked.

Answer (score 2):

The beta label has been removed.